# .htaccess - redirect request to directory and any of it's files and subdirectories to single URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Redirect `/product/` and any of it's files or subdirectories to `http://example.com` without appending the file, subdirectory or params to it.

Example:

`http://example.com/something/product` -> `http://example.com`

`http://example.com/something/product/some-dir/` -> `http://example.com`

`http://example.com/something/product/?foo=bar` -> `http://example.com`

`http://example.com/something/product/some-dir/some-file.html` -> `http://example.com`

I've tried quite a few `RewriteRule` solutions that I've found on StackOverflow (most of which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)) but they always append the subdirectories, files or params. For example:

`http://example.com/something/product/some-dir/` redirects to `http://example.com/some-dir`

Where as I'd like it (and anything else under and including `products`) to redirect to just `http://example.com`

Here's an example of one of the .htaccess files I tired that failed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products\/.+ http://example.com [NC,L]
```

**UPDATE**

I've just deleted the .htaccess file on my local machine but I'm still getting the redirects. Could it have been that changes I made to .htaccess file while testing weren't getting noticed? Maybe one of the solutions I had would have worked!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang updated :)

Comment: Browsers may aggressively cache redirects. Since deleting .htaccess, test them again in a different browser or a private/incognito session.